# Network issue with Centos 7

Tags: nat, virtualbox, gateway, centos7

I've just installed the minimum install of Centos 7 in VirtualBox. When trying to ssh from my local into my VM I realise the VM is on a different gateway / ip range.

My home network is on 10.0.1.x and Centos is on 10.0.2.x. I've tried setting gateway in `/etc/sysconfig/network` to 10.0.1.1 but it has no affect. I've also tried playing around with the network settings for the adapter but no change. I'm using NAT for the settings in VirtualBox. I'm not great with networking so this might be a simple fix.

If possible I'd like the network settings to be auto-discovered as this VM might jump around networks a bit.

Comment: when you use nat in virtualbox you don't neet to set anything, because virtualbox has an internal dhcp server, the gateway in most common case is an ip in the same subnet.

Comment: But what if I want my router to be the DHCP server, as currently the vm is in a different ip range and I can't connect to it.

Comment: use bridge in virtual network system of your vm.

Comment: @c4f4t0r see comment on answer below re bridge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A NAT interface will allow outbound traffic from your vm but not inbound.

Create a bridge interface on your host then in your VirtualBox VM network settings select the Bridged Adapter from the 'Attached To' dropdown and then the bridge interface from the "Name' dropdown.

Of course, if you don't really care about having separate subnets for your host and VMs then can can just select Bridged Adapter and then eth0 as the host bridge interface. Your host and vm will then be on the same network.

Here's a link on how to setup bridge interfaces on CentOS:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-linux-kvm-virtualization-bridged-networking-with-libvirt/

Comment: I don't want to do this because I also run services from my host. If I do this I'll have to customise the ports which I don't really want to do. Surely it could just get an IP assigned from my routers DHCP service and be on the same IP range?

Comment: Why would you need to customize ports? Your host and VM will have different IPs

Comment: :/ I always thought of it as a network bridge (i.e. they shared the same IP), not an adapter bridge.

Comment: Nah.. your VM has a different MAC address and will pickup a DHCP address... assuming DHCP is active on your 10.0.1.x subnet.. otherwise assign a static